# Scrappy CSS selector returning empty list

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm trying to build a scraper to retrieve translations from wiktionary.
I'm calling this function that should return a list with all the translations of the argument word, but it returns an empty list.
The command `response.css('ol').re(r'(?<=>)\w+(?=<)')` is working on scrappy shell, though.
The word I'm using as a test is "Hallo"

```
 def scrape_translation(word):
        url = "https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/" + word
        response = HtmlResponse(url=url)
        translation_list = response.css('ol').re(r'(?<=>)\w+(?=<)')
        print(translation_list)
```

I'm using Python 3.6.4

Comment: Which python version do you use (python 2 or 3)?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HtmlResponse is used to convert HTML string to HtmlResponse object.
So you need to add HTML string as argument body:

```
import requests

def scrape_translation(word):
    url = "https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/" + word
    r = requests.get(url)
    response = HtmlResponse(url=url, body = r.content)
    translation_list = response.css('ol').re(r'(?<=>)\w+(?=<)')
    print(translation_list)

scrape_translation('Hallo')
```

I used requests library, but there are other python modules which can extract HTML from URL.